# Debugging the website slowness cause

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, performance-testing

I am investigating the slowness issue for one of the pages in my application. On investigation I see that one of my static normal sized files (it keeps on changing some time css other time js)like JS/Css/image is stucked and take much time in downloading and on looking at the network time line  of chrome browser I found following values-

Blocking- 5.2 min

DNS lookup-81.00ms

Connecting---1.000ms

Sending------ 1.000ms

waiting------ 120.00ms

recieveing---- 4.500 ms

I want to figure it out that it is problem of web server or clinet network. has any one faced such issue or Can any one please help me suggesting like that how could I debug the exact root cause of blocking. Is there any tools for that ?

Any help will be appreciated!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If its a .net framework app, you can use **dot trace** tool to detect bottle neck issue, [www.jetbrains.com/profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

Comment: First of all, could you please list out tools and technologies used to develop this app (I know you have tagged this question but that's brief.) And, is this issue for all your web pages or for a particular page? Is it happening only when you start the application? Do you have caching mechanism? Give some more info like these to get an idea

Comment: @Sam:This is in asp.net MVC 4. And this is happening for a particular page. yes we have caching mechanism too.This issue does not occurred at first browsing of the page. When user re navigate to that page or refresh then this issues comes and it is intermittently.